# How to maintain scroll position after postback in web application created in visual studio 2003

Tags: visual-studio, web-applications

Is there a way to maintain scroll position after a postback in visual studio 2003.

In visual studio 2005 I can achieve this by setting **MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback** attribute of page directive to true.

How can I do this without setting location.href property???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the 1.1 Framework, you're looking for [SmartNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.smartnavigation.aspx).  It's deprecated for the MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback in 2.0.  Don't get your hopes up, it's mediocre at best. :)

Comment: Ya got it. Can you tell me the difference between these two

Comment: To my knowledge, "Maintain" drops all the anti-flicker stuff and just does what it says, keep the scroll position where it was.  The best way to avoid the postback stuff that SmartNav is supposed to eliminate is Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

SmartNavigation will work for you. It is available in .Net 1.1.